# App not asking for permission upon installing

Tags: android, kotlin, android-permissions, splash-screen

Why is this not working? I've modified the Manifest too. 
It is not asking for permission as I've coded. It's behaving as if I'm not even requesting for any permission.

I've made a splash screen and I want it to ask for permission before it goes to the MainActivity.

Splash screen should last for 1sec.

```
class SplashActivity : AppCompatActivity() {


var permissionsString = arrayOf(
       Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
       Manifest.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS,
       Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE,
       Manifest.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS,
       Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO)


override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash)


    if (hasPermissions(this@SplashActivity,*permissionsString)){

        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this@SplashActivity,permissionsString,131)

    }else{
        Handler().postDelayed({
            val startAct = Intent(this@SplashActivity,MainActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(startAct)
            this.finish()},1000)
    }



}

override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode: Int, permissions: Array<out String>, grantResults: IntArray) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults)
    when(requestCode){
        131 ->{
            if (grantResults.isNotEmpty()
                    && grantResults[0]==PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                    && grantResults[1]==PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                    && grantResults[2]==PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                    && grantResults[3]==PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                    && grantResults[4]==PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                Handler().postDelayed({
                    val startAct = Intent(this@SplashActivity,MainActivity::class.java)
                    startActivity(startAct)
                    this.finish()},1000)
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(this@SplashActivity,"Grant it Please",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                this.finish()
            }
                return
        }
        else->{
            Toast.makeText(this@SplashActivity,"Something wrong",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            this.finish()
            return
        }
    }

}


fun hasPermissions(context: Context,vararg permissions: String): Boolean{
    var hasAllPermissions = true

    for (permission in permissions){
        val res = context.checkCallingOrSelfPermission(permission)
        if (res!=PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            hasAllPermissions = false
        }
    }

    return hasAllPermissions
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your

targetSdkVersion

in project gradle file.
It should be >= 23 to call run-time permission, otherwise will take permission automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Thats because your `if condition` is wrong. It should on include NOT operator to ask for permission as below:

```
 if (!hasPermissions(this@SplashActivity,*permissionsString)) {

   //Ask for permission
 }
```

Ask for permission if you don't have the permission. In your case, you are checking if you have permission, then ask for permission which is wrong.

Comment: yeah!..but it's asking two permissions only. why is that?